# Getting empty property error while traversing json using php

Tags: php, json, solr

I am using Apache Solr Engine to provide suggestions to the user based on the input keyword.

I have a json response in the following format.

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "mySuggester": {
            "A Ga": {
                "numFound": 2,
                "suggestions": [
                {
                    "term": "<b>A Ga</b>me of Thrones",
                    "weight": 0,
                    "payload": "Book"
                },
                {
                    "term": "<b>A Ga</b>teway to Heaven",
                    "weight": 0,
                    "payload": "Book"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Key `A Ga`is user input, that is, based on this key, the suggestions are provided. Now Solr returns this JSON which is stored in my `$response` variable in php and the key `A Ga` is contained in the variable `$inp`.

In my code, there is a line which is,

```
$noOfSuggestions =  $response->suggest->mySuggester->$inp->numFound;
```

I am getting a **cannot access empty property** error at this line. Is my usage of `$inp` correct?

Thanks!

EDIT: This is `var_dump($response);`

```
object(Apache_Solr_Response)#60 (5) { ["_response":protected]=> object(Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response)#50 (5) { ["_statusCode":"Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response":private]=> int(200) ["_statusMessage":"Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response":private]=> string(2) "OK" ["_mimeType":"Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response":private]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["_encoding":"Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response":private]=> string(5) "UTF-8" ["_responseBody":"Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response":private]=> string(511) "{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":2},"suggest":{"mySuggester":{"A Ga":{"numFound":2,"suggestions":[{"term":"A Game of Thrones","weight":0,"payload":"Book"},{"term":"A Gateway to Heaven","weight":0,"payload":"Book"}]}}}} " } ["_isParsed":protected]=> bool(false) ["_parsedData":protected]=> NULL ["_createDocuments":protected]=> bool(true) ["_collapseSingleValueArrays":protected]=> bool(true) }
```

Comment: Do this and it will make easy for you. **$array = json_decode( $json, true );**

Comment: You should be able to get it using `$response->suggest->mySuggester->{$inp}->numFound;` (note the curly braces). If not, can you post a `var_dump`?

Comment: @jeroen I have provided the var_dump in the EDIT. Can you tell me what is the significance of curly brace?

Comment: As per your EDIT, You are not getting valid json.

Comment: How is it not valid?! @RaviHirani

Comment: You need to get the json from the solr object first, `$response` is a lot more than the example you show on top.

Comment: Solr returns a json object, so what do you mean by _get the json from solr object_ @jeroen Thanks!

Comment: Not according to your `var_dump()`: `object(Apache_Solr_Response)`...